# How to let flaggers know that they have the wrong idea about low quality posts?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, low-quality-posts

New as I am to reviewing low quality posts, I'm noticing a lot of the time the post is flagged because it is flat out wrong, rather than "severe format or content problems".

However, my understanding is that answers that are comprehendable, tackle the problem, but are wrong should be downvoted, not low quality flagged.

Therefore, I put "Looks OK" for these (and downvote the answer if appropriate).   I'd like to be able to educate the recipient of this decision though.   Should I add a comment saying "flaggers, please downvote if the answer is wrong.  'wrong' does not mean 'low quality' or ... what?

Comment: Doesn't the review queue give you the  opportunity to downvote as your action of choice?

Comment: Glancing at reviews such as http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5896154 these may be system flats rather than user flags.

Comment: I think @RobertHarvey is pointing out that my question is very silly (IE the way I was using the review queue).   Knowing that there are system flags is also good.   I have to wait 18 hours to find out if, were I to click "downvote" as the option (obviously) then does it let me say why!

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate, because the referred ticket assumes you even know what a disputed flag is.   My question comes up in the absence of that knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The queue includes automatically flagged posts, and audits, so you can't assume that anyone has flagged incorrectly.

However, By clicking Looks OK (or editing) you *are* already telling the flagger that there was a problem. This will "dispute" the flag, which shows up in the original flaggers flag history.

You don't know who the flagger is, or even if there actually is one so it's impossible to communicate with them save with the binary good/bad. Your job in the queue is to remove it from the queue somehow. It's focused on the post in the queue not the author of the post or the person who put it in the queue. I think you're overthinking this...

Comment: Thanks - I'm hoping I can tell them _why_ the post should not have been flagged as low quality.

Comment: You can't @Green.

Comment: A bit of feedback to the flagger is probably nice, especially when the disputed rate is way above average. Maybe SO could display the personal quantile in the personal flag history for the disputed rate or send a message reminding of the goals of flagging once in a while when you are in the top ten disputed rate fraction. I therefore don't think it was overthink, rather a real present little problem which could get a bit more attention.

Comment: People get temporarily banned if you have too many erroneous flags @Trilaron, along with warnings when you're reaching that stage and links to more material to help. The best thing you can do is feed back into the system...